# endless horizontal stretch with unknown width of children

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is to create div which can expand endlessly to the right.
This is quite easy, there is a couple of [working](http://jsfiddle.net/S6Abd/8/) examples.

However, I have trouble with adapting from:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
     ...
</div>
```

To the design I'm using:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="project">
    <div class = "textContainer">text Container 1.1 </div>
    <div class = "imgContainer">img Container 1.1 </div>
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="project">
    <div class = "textContainer">text Container 2.1 </div>
    <div class = "imgContainer">img Container 2.1 </div>
    <div class = "imgContainer">img Container 2.2 </div>
    <div class = "imgContainer">img Container 2.3 </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Where textContainer and imgContainer are specialized classes to contain the obvious(Important note: I want the imgContainer to fill 100% of height and adjust horizontally to keep aspect-ratio).

To give better idea of my intentions (almost) working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eck6yx81/33/). Remove the comment in container to see desired effect.

Comment: imgContainers keeps an img tag. It also sometimes contains an div with text which should be on top of img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the floats. Convert all children to `inline-block`s, and set `white-space: nowrap` on the `.container` and sub containers (`.project`). This will force everything to a single line, and will make the width of the container fit his children.

```css
#container {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 40px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.project {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: blue;
}

.textContainer {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.project, .imgContainer, .textContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="project">
    <div class="textContainer">text Container 1.1 </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">img Container 1.1 </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">img Container 1.2 </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">img Container 1.3 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project">
    <div class="textContainer">text Container 2.1 </div>
    <div class="imgContainer"><img src="http://myhswm.org/images/sized/images/animals/anjo-256x256.jpg"></div>
    <div class="imgContainer">img Container 2.2 </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">img Container 2.3 </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">img Container 2.4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great! However, it falls apart when I put an img in imgContainer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8n01owu9/9/)

Comment: Fixed. Text-less blocks needs a vertical alignment as well.